# How can I use font icons for CKEdit buttons instead of images

Tags: css, fonts, icons, ckeditor, glyphicons

I am looking for the cleanest way to use css font icons that match my site's preexisting icon pack instead of having to create images to use in the plugin folder.

I am open to writing custom solutions as well as using plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if they have to match them 1 on 1, or you just want to have the same type of icons as you had, but I recently ran into and implemented font icons from [fontello.com](http://fontello.com) that have many existing icons and supports custom icons if really needed.

Comment: I have my own icons in font files.  I would like to know the best way to use them in place of the icons that are placed inside the **Plugins > PluginName > images** folder.  replacing the icon path in the plugin config with the correct character code just puts an empty "image" for the icon.

Comment: @Zagloo The only way i've found to do this is to rip out the inline styles that are attached to each button and then do something like this:

`.cke_button__cut_icon:after {
  content: "R";
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 2px;
}`

you would have to replace the content with your own font code